# As the file path changes password.blade in laravel?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.1, reset-password

I'm doing a simple application laravel 5.1, and I want to reset the password for users. I dont have a problem with that.

I just have not found a way to change the path of some files.
Among them is file "password.blade.php" which is what is sent to the user's mail containing the link to the token. This file must be in the Resources / views / emails / route.

[image]

Would you like to change: the name and path of the file. ?
Or if you can select a different view to be sent?

Thank you, any information would be appreciated ).

Comment: I know this is not what you are asking but why can't you just edit inside the file so a different view would be sent?

Comment: I just want to change the location of the file. Example I want to put in the auth folder, it can be ?. I'm using the methods that laravel provides: (getEmail, postEmail, getReset, postReset). As stated in the documentation.

Comment: can you explain little more? you just want to relocate your `password.blade.php` file ? right? and also you want them to access this file from new location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an $emailView variable in PasswordBroker.

```
/**
 * The view of the password reset link e-mail.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $emailView;
```

If you set this to your view in your Password Controller, you should be able to change it's path and name.

If it doesn't work you can overwrite the emailResetLink function in your Password controller and change the view there. Here is the one from Laravel 5.2. You can get 5.1 from your PasswordBroker.php if it's different.

```
/**
 * Send the password reset link via e-mail.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @param  string  $token
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @return int
 */
public function emailResetLink(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token, Closure $callback = null)
{
    // We will use the reminder view that was given to the broker to display the
    // password reminder e-mail. We'll pass a "token" variable into the views
    // so that it may be displayed for an user to click for password reset.
    $view = $this->emailView;

    return $this->mailer->send($view, compact('token', 'user'), function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
        $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());

        if (! is_null($callback)) {
            call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much helped me a lot.

Create a new method in PasswordBroken file that changes the value of the emailview variable.

$this->emailView = $value;

But there will be another way to change the value of this variable from the controller?

Try Password :: emailview and did not work. I'm new (.

Like thank you very much.

Comment: It also occurs to me to add a new parameter to the function, but not if it will be right to edit stuff. You about this friend??

Comment: No problem. Did you try setting protected $emailView to your view in your PasswordController? That's what it's being retrieved from emailResetLink function.